# HTML id in a php loop + modal (jquery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I used a loop to get and display all the details for each event that a user added. Inside the loop i included a button for a modal. The thing is if i have more than one event, the `<button class="btn btn-success" id="read">Read More</button>` won't work. How will work around this?

This the php code

```
<?php

            while ($event_row = mysqli_fetch_array($event_data)){
                $event_img = $event_row['event_img'];
                $img_src = "../admin/eventImages/".$event_img;
                echo '<div class="col-sm-6 p0">
                        <div class="box-two proerty-item">
                            <div class="item-thumb">
                                <img src="'.$img_src.'">
                            </div>
                            <div class="item-entry overflow">
                                <h5><a href="property-1.html">'.$event_row['event_name'].'</a></h5>
                            <div class="dot-hr"></div>
                                <span class="pull-left"><b> Date: </b>'.date("Y-m-d h:i A", strtotime($event_row['event_start'])).'</span>
                                <span class="pull-left"><b>Location: </b>'.$event_row['event_location'].'</span>
                                <div class="property-icon">
                                    <button class="btn btn-success" id="read">Read More</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
            }
            ?>
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $("#read").click(function(){
    ("#readmore").modal("show");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `class` selector. Also add some unique attribute to each button for identification.

`<button class="btn btn-success read-more" id="read-more-1">Read More</button>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(".read-more").click(function(){
    console.log($(this).id);
    $("#readmore").modal("show");
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple buttons, than you need to use `class` instead of `id` as ID is always unique:

**Change in HTML:**

```
<button class="btn btn-success readmore">Read More</button>
```

**Change in JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  $(".readmore").click(function(){
    ("#readmore").modal("show");
 });
});
```